# Use other service from a service method in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In this example it raise the exception, and doesn't recognize $scope service.
How can I reference other services from the service method?

```
.factory('newService', function($scope) {
  return {
    function : function(data) {
      $scope.var = 'a';
    }
  }
})
```

I Guess it might be more of a question about JavaScript than AngularJS.

Comment: Well.. did it help? :)

Answer (score 0):

The `$scope` service is unique to Controllers (and directives, but in directives it isn't being injected).

Try another service name which you defined in another factory or just any other angular service like `$http` and it will work...

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should inject service, only after that use it in service. Something like this:

```
var func;

func = function($scope) {
  return console.log('work');
};

angular.module('mainModule').factory('newService', ['$scope', func]);
```